# JVMCFRE003 bad major version

Tags: java, ant, websphere

I have build a jar file using Ant on my Windows OS using Oracle Java 1.7. When I deploy the jar on my CentOS machine (which has WAS 8.5.5) running on open JDK 1.8, get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=com/ac/ps/ft/home/ad/cr/testclass, offset=6
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:853)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:763)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:586)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:182)
```

I'm not sure what exactly is the problem. I have tried compiling with Java 1.8 but it still gives the same error. Please help.

Comment: Can you triple-check your java version in messages.log? Your runtime is probably different/older than you think.

Comment: Adding onto that, the JDK used to compile tells us some, but not all. If you have a hex editor handy you can see definitively the compliance level of the .class by looking at byte offset 6 and 7: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout

Comment: @covener The stack trace says this is full profile, so the message header would be in SystemOut.log.  I suspect the default Java 6 is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JVMCFRE003 looks like an IBM Java error code, so I don't think your application server is running with Open JDK. You could confirm the java version used by looking at the top of your SystemOut log.

If you're using traditional Websphere Application Server (rather than liberty) then it will always use the JRE that was installed with the app server.

In this case, use installation manager to make sure you have an appropriate Java level installed, then use the [managesdk command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_managesdk.html?lang=en) to enable it.